# My alarm clock is alarm when I restart my phone immediately

Tags: android

I am doing an alarm timer, although not to the alarm time, it was called when I reboot. I used BroadcastReceiver to reboot and load data backup DataBase. Here is my code :

```
public class SampleBootReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    int ID;
    String phone,sms,day,hour,min,rule,pending;
    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        DatabaseHandler db ;
        db=new DatabaseHandler(context);
        List<Contact> contactsList = db.getAllContacts();

        for (Contact cn : contactsList) {
              ID =cn.getId();
            phone = cn.getPhoneNumber();
            sms = cn.getSmsBody();
            day= cn.getDay();
            hour =cn.getHour();
            min =cn.getMinutes();
            rule =cn.getRule();
            if (rule.equalsIgnoreCase("everyday")){
               SetEveryday(context,hour,min,day,ID);
            }
            // Writing Contacts to log

        }

    }
    public void SetEveryday(Context context,String hour ,String minute,String date, int idAlarm){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hour));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minute));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(date));
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("ID",idAlarm);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idAlarm, myIntent, pendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 240000, pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(context,"livsfgsg"+idAlarm,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Your post does not actually contain any question. Anything you need help with?

Comment: I don't want my alarm clock is alarm although not to the alarm time when I restart my phone